# Cordova trying to dial telephone number

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cordova

I am trying to dial a phone number in iOS, however I only have the simulator and an iPod Touch to test on.

The code uses something along the lines of:

```
window.location.href = 'tel:01234567890';
```

Working fine with Android, but in iOS it dies with:

> Failed to load webpage with error: The URL can't be shown

Now, I do realise this has been asked before, but the general consensus from some time ago was "It doesn't work, you'll need to use a plugin".  There haven't been many questions on this for some time though, and what questions there are seem to suggest it works when doing it programmatically (as above with `window.location.href`).  I have tried the [iOS PhoneDialer](https://github.com/mchristie/PhoneGap-ios-PhoneDialer/) and the newer version of the same plugin, but both have errors in XCode (`ARC forbids explicit message send of 'release'`) - a bit of faffing and I can get this running, but then PhoneGap doesn't find the plugin - it really feels like I'm hitting a brick wall with this method, and I can't believe something as simple as this requires something so over the top.

I know you cannot auto-dial/auto-call a number for security reasons, but all I need to do is open the dialer with number pre-populated, which is surely no different to a `mailto:info@example.com` link opening your email client with the sender pre-populated?

So, my questions are:

- Has this changed with a recent update to PhoneGap, iOS or XCode?
- Or, is it a case that I cannot do this on an iPod or Simulator, and it will work fine on an iPhone?
- How can I fix it? :)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You didn't specify which version of Cordova you are using so I'm going to assume version > 3.

Make sure that [InAppBrowser](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser), a [plugin](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser) since version 3, [is installed](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface_add_features) and then open the link by calling it through Javascript like this:

```
window.open('tel:12345678', '_system')
```

`_system` will open it with the systems own browser which in turn will open the call dialog, if you use it against http://maps.apple.com/ it will open in the maps app and similar for other apps which opens for special urls.

**Remarks:**

- As described [in the docs of the InAppBrowser plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) the `window.open` function won't be set automatically. You have to do it your self: `window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;`. Instead you can directly use `cordova.InAppBrowser.open('tel:12345678', '_system');`
- Make sure your number doesn't have any blankspaces in it (the +
  prefix is okay). For example you could use a function like the following,
  assuming `num` is a string.

Function:

```
function placeCall(num) {
    if (window.cordova) {
        cordova.InAppBrowser.open('tel:' + num.replace(/\s/g,''), '_system');
    }
}
```

Comment: This did not work on the iPod Touch nor the Simulator.  Should I expect it to work on an iPhone though?  I get the following in the console, so I assume the plugin is working: `[6278:907] THREAD WARNING: ['InAppBrowser'] took '124.701904' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.`

Comment: @gaqzi i am trying to get it to work since several days but unfortunately I am failing all the time. I have tested the code on `IOS 10` in `iPhone 6s`. Nothing happens when the phone number is clicked. Could you please help me find out why I can not get this code to work? Will it work on simulator as well?

Answer (score 7):

Below Code works perfectly fine for iphone:-

***window.open('tel:123456', '_system');***

Simulator doesn't support dialer. No need to waste time.

Comment: Thanks for the last line!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the phone number in your href also doesn't have any formatting in it, as on iOS it causes the link not to work in a PhoneGap App. So for example, use tel:0390005555, and not tel:(03) 9000 5555.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is a Cordova issue.  I know in native iOS you cannot bring up the dialer on the simulator or on an iPod touch.  You will need to test this on an actual iPhone.

Comment: It works perfectly fine on the iPhone. The simulator won't work because it can't dial.

Answer (score 0):

Use Cordova's plugin [cordova-plugin-call-number](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-call-number?activeTab=readme)

- Cordova Version = 12.0.0
- XCode Version = 14.2

It is working fine in iPhone and iPad. Please follow the following steps.

1. Install plugin

   `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-call-number`
2. Call the plugin in your JS file
   Method Signature:

   `window.plugins.CallNumber.callNumber(onSuccess, onError, number, bypassAppChooser);`

number: Pass actual 'phone number' as string value(e.g. "9000000000")

Actual Implementation e.g.

`<div v-else-if="$q.platform.is.mobile" @click="gotoCall('9000000000')">
                  
</div>

 methods: {
      gotoCall(phoneNumber){
        window.plugins.CallNumber.callNumber(onSuccess, onError, phoneNumber, true);
    }`

Answer (score -4):

I know this is a late answer time.

Try by adding `//` to the url. Like this `tel://xxxxxxxxx` and see if it works.

Worked for me in IOS 8.4, iPhone 6, 6+ as of today.

Comment: You don't need to add the //. Works as described in the accepted answer on iOS 9.2.1