# document.location = broken in Cordova 3.6 on Android?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova

My JQueryMobile app has been sending texts by composing an SMS URL, viz

```
var url = sendMessageUrl(message, navigator.userAgent);
document.location.href = url
```

This was fine on cordova@3.5.0-0.2.7 but fails silently on cordova@3.6.3-0.2.13

Should I be doing something different now?

Comment: Looks like it might just be special URI schemes - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7711

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like special URI schemes are now not whitelisted. You can get around the issue by opening with the InAppBrowser

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19642942/97777